# Ratpack Jackson (json) render same object but different response format

Tags: json, jackson, ratpack

I'm using RatPack 1.1.1 with Jackson and it renders the same object "Product" differently.  The first "Product" within my main object is returned with the attribute "productCode" but for the others for the same product, it returns only an attribute value "product" with the value of the "productCode"!

Why? is it normal?

Response from the rendering:

```
ProductCharacteristics=[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "product" : {
        "productCode" : "cold-brew"
   },
  "attributeCode" : "family",
  "attributeValue" : "Kits",
  }, {
  "id" : 2,
  "product" : "cold-brew",
  "attributeCode" : "Couleur",
  "attributeValue" : "Noir",
  }, {
  "id" : 3,
  "product" : "cold-brew",
  "attributeCode" : "Matériaux",
  "attributeValue" : "Verre-Plastique",
  }
]
```

Definition of my entity ProductCharacteristic:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@ToString
class ProductCharacteristic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "product_code")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    Product product;
}
```

Definition of my entity Product:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="productCode")
@ToString
public class Product {
    @Id
    String productCode;
}
```

Why the response is not like that:

```
ProductCharacteristics=[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "product" : {
        "productCode" : "cold-brew"
   },
  "attributeCode" : "family",
  "attributeValue" : "Kits",
  }, {

  "id" : 2,
  "product" : {
        "productCode" : "cold-brew"
   },
  "attributeCode" : "Couleur",
  "attributeValue" : "Noir",
  }, {

  "id" : 3,
  "product" : {
        "productCode" : "cold-brew"
   },
  "attributeCode" : "Matériaux",
  "attributeValue" : "Verre-Plastique",
  }
]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi George, is it possible to share more code? Perhaps even a reproducible sample.
As it stands it's hard to know what went wrong with just the data model here.

It's hard for me to parse this sentence:

> The first "Product" within my main object is returned with the attribute "productCode" but for the others for the same product, it returns only an attribute value "product" with the value of the "productCode"!

Can you post the actual objects with some code sample to get a clearer picture of what's going on?

Comment: Do you mind showing how this result gets rendered? That is, can you show the handler and how the data gets loaded to be passed to the client?